# struts2 annotation there is no action mapped for namespace / and action name

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

You may find this as duplicate but I'm not getting what is wrong with my code, so please help me out

I'm switching from using `struts.xml` to struts 2 `convention-plugin` and having problem with mapping action

```
there is no action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/eCensus]
```

**Project Strucure**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>eCensus</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.shantaram.ecensus.actions</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**LoginAction class**

```
package com.shantaram.ecensus.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("prepare Login Action");
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.execute();
    }

}
```

**Jars I'm using**

[image]

Comment: Where is your struts.xml file?

Comment: @Dez Annotation based configuration doesn't requre `struts.xml`

Comment: Do you have `pom.xml`?

Comment: @RomanC: this project is without maven, so no pom.xml

Comment: Do you have any exception at startup?

Comment: Can you post server log with debug level enabled?

Comment: *Annotation based configuration doesn't requre struts.xml* - says who?

Comment: @RomanC : I `clean` `build` my project , then it thrown exception, I had added `asm-commoms3.3.jar` , now it is working, thank u for your `valuable time`

Comment: @AleksandrM : I had followed some tutorials e.g. http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/struts2-beginner-tutorial-with-annotations and in those tutorials there were not used `struts.xml`

Comment: @AleksandrM: would tell me when to use `struts.xml` in `Annotation` based configuration